# How to clear redux store for React-admin?

Tags: redux, react-admin

I want to clear react admin redux store while logging out from the application.
How can i do that?

Is there a way to access redux store of react admin, like I have to access resource dashboard which has all the potential data (like userID, homeId etc).
I need to send this data with the payload, of another API request while I'm on some other page/resource. How can i do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is better.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    ...formReducers,
    routing
});


export default (state, action) =>
  rootReducer(action.type === 'USER_LOGOUT' ? undefined : state, action);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).